# Inconsistency in coordinates representation in GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, geopandas, shapely

I have list of Shapely Points in GeoSeries.

`coords.head():`

```
0    POINT (-26.17690 80.81700)
1    POINT (-15.54390 80.61700)
2    POINT (-20.67690 80.36700)
3      POINT (6.10610 80.83300)
4     POINT (17.63910 79.88300)
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

When trying to get list of zipped coordinates using command `pd.Series(zip(coords.geometry.x, coords.geometry.y)).head()` I get next sample:

```
0              (-26.1769, 80.817)
1              (-15.5439, 80.617)
2              (-20.6769, 80.367)
3    (6.1061000000000005, 80.833)
4     (17.63909999999999, 79.883)
dtype: object
```

By the way example of `coords.geometry.x.head()`:

```
0   -26.1769
1   -15.5439
2   -20.6769
3     6.1061
4    17.6391
dtype: float64
```

Also strange thing is that when I try to reproduce results:

```
new_coords = [(-26.17690, 80.81700),
(-15.54390, 80.61700),
(-20.67690, 80.36700),
(6.10610, 80.83300),
(17.63910, 79.88300)]
new_coords = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(p) for p in new_coords])
pd.Series(zip(new_coords.geometry.x, new_coords.geometry.y))
new_coords
```

Zip doesn't behave oddly:

```
0    POINT (-26.17690 80.81700)
1    POINT (-15.54390 80.61700)
2    POINT (-20.67690 80.36700)
3      POINT (6.10610 80.83300)
4     POINT (17.63910 79.88300)
dtype: geometry
```

Main goal here is to get **accurate** value of coordinates in order to merge frames of data, thus it is not acceptable that zip returns similar value but not the same.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to *string formatting* in whatever the `Point` class is, the actual values are probably the same. This has **nothing** to do with `zip`

Comment: GeoPandas truncates WKT representation to 5 decimals in your case. See [Display options](https://geopandas.org/data_structures.html?highlight=wkt#display-options) in GeoPandas docs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like @juanpa.arrivillaga is correct. When executing statement `[float(p) for p in coords.geometry.x][:5]` I get the same numbers:

```
[-26.1769, -15.5439, -20.6769, 6.1061000000000005, 17.63909999999999]
```

So input data isn't changed by zip.